# I need to compare and retain multiple values from a Java Stream

Tags: java

I'm rewritting a method using Stream, but I kinda stuck. For the short story, it's a method used to retrieve available skills for a player. The whole list of skills is stored into a player template (getTemplate(), list reachable with getTemplate().getSkills()). The player also owns its own already known skills, stored into a Map (in this case I only use getSkillLevel, which simply send back the skill level if known or -1 if unknown).

It must be filtered by some conditions, such as :

- The template skill must be "learnable" by the player, according current player level (it's the filter content)
- The template skill is added on the list if the player doesn't know yet the skill (result of getSkillLevel == -1) or if the current player skill level is lower than the template skill.

A GeneralSkillNode is a container holding following informations :

- skill id (named getId())
- skill level (named getValue())
- minimum level to learn it (named getMinLvl())

getTemplate().getSkills() is the whole learnable skills this player can learn (each skill entry is listed here no matter the level), which is a List.

The problem comes than it currently register ALL skills level range. Let's say there are 18 levels for a given skill id (1-1-5, 1-2-5, 1-3-5,... 1-18-80), it will add the 18 GeneralSkillNode for skill id 1. **I need to filter by skill id and retain ONLY, for each skill id, the biggest possible level (which can be tested, if you followed my explanations, using getValue()).** If I use a Comparator with .max(, it will only retrieve the maximum level for a single skill.

I search the most elegant way to do it. Thanks in advance for any help !

Here is my current result :

```
/**
 * @return a {@link Collection} of all available {@link GeneralSkillNode}s (being general or autoGet) <b>of maximal level</b> for this {@link Player}.
 */
public Collection<GeneralSkillNode> getAllAvailableSkills()
{
    final List<GeneralSkillNode> result = new ArrayList<>();

    getTemplate().getSkills().stream().filter(s -> s.getMinLvl() <= getLevel()).forEach(s ->
    {
        final int playerSkillLevel = getSkillLevel(s.getId());
        if (playerSkillLevel == -1 || playerSkillLevel < s.getValue())
            result.add(s);
    });
    return result;
}
```

**Edit : Thanks for helping me, the final version looks like that now :**

```
    /**
 * @return a {@link Collection} of all available {@link GeneralSkillNode}s (being general or autoGet) <b>of maximal level</b> for this {@link Player}.
 */
public Collection<GeneralSkillNode> getAllAvailableSkills()
{
    final List<GeneralSkillNode> result = new ArrayList<>();

    getTemplate().getSkills().stream().filter(s -> s.getMinLvl() <= getLevel()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getId(), Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getValue())))).forEach((i, s) ->
    {
        final int playerSkillLevel = getSkillLevel(i);
        if (playerSkillLevel == -1 || playerSkillLevel < s.get().getValue())
            result.add(s.get());
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you manipulate the values of GeneralSkillNode? Like 'updating' the skill level? Or can you rewrite the GeneralSkillNode.equals() and GeneralSkillNode.hashCode() methods?

Comment: Those nodes are generated from XML data, and aren't willing to be edited on the fly (one time loading on server start, then never processed again).I can override generic equals / hashCode if it's needed, yup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the maximum level for each skill, you can do a `groupingBy` to separate each skill, then a `maxBy` to get the highest level per skill.

```
getTemplate().getSkills().stream().filter(s -> s.getMinLvl() <= getLevel())
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getId(), 
                                  Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getValue()))));
```